# Creating an arbitrary entry in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I am working with `memoir` for my forthcoming book, and I need to insert a reference in the table of contents pointing to a photo colour inset in the middle of the book. The photo inset will be inserted with Adobe Acrobat once the book is completed, and I was wondering how I can create an arbitrary reference to it in the table of contents, a line at the end of the TOC saying something like:

> "A photo inset is between pages 130 and 131".

I believe that there is no need of MWE, but happy to supply it if needed.

Comment: Index=table of contents?

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I have corrected the question. I mean Table of Contents. It can also be an arbitrary Table of Colour photos as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add anything you like to the table of contents with `\addtocontents`.

In the example, I add a `\label` in the page after which the photo will be inserted; with the help of `\AtEndDvi`, writing the entry in the `.toc` file is delayed until the end of the document. I think this is preferable to adding the code at the end, so everything related to the inset is kept together.

Add the formatting you like to the description sentence.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{refcount,atenddvi}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}

\kant

\chapter{Second}

\kant

\label{photoinset}
\AtEndDvi{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{\bigskipamount}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \normalfont\noindent
    A photo inset is between pages \pageref{photoinset}
    and \the\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{photoinset}+1\relax\par
  }%
}

\kant

\chapter{Third}

\kant

\end{document}
```

[image]